# Positive and negative values in fields

Tags: python

I want to make if field1 is a negative integer then field 2 will be the same integer but positive. but if field1 is any positive then field2 will be always 0.0

Example:

```
if
 field1 = -180:
     field2 = 180
if field1 = 180
    field2 = 0.0
```

Comment: I guess when you say "field" you mean "variable"? Are you aware of Python's [comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
if field1 < 0:
    field2 = abs(field1)
else:
    field2 = 0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a number is negative by comparing it to zero.

```
if field1 < 0:
    field2 = -field1
else:
    field2 = 0.0
```

Or more succinctly:

```
field2 = (-field1 if field1 < 0 else 0.0)
```